# CURL returning different responses

Tags: json, api, curl

My code is this:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Content-type: application/json','Content-Length: ' . strlen($content), 'Cache-Control: no-cache'));
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

if($result===FALSE)
{echo "cURL ERROR:".curl_error($ch);}

echo $result;
```

The problem is the fact that sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.

When it works I get a valid JSON response, like:
[Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q96Ua.jpg),
but when it doesn't, I get this:
[Not Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MV6ZV.jpg)

I should mention that I don't have access to the API server. Can anyone help me with any idea? Thank you!

Comment: You are either querying two different pages, or the API is returning two different results. The first page you are querying returns JSON. The second page you are querying returns HTML. As such, you'll have to parse them differently.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.

I'm testing from 2 different pages, but CURLOPT_URL ($url) is the same.
Though I'm testing using 2 different forms on 2 different pages, everything is the same: HTML code, js code (for Ajax), $content of CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS. The only difference is in the CURL $result.
Most of the cases when the errors occur are when adding a GET parameter to the URL of the submitted form (ex: https://page.com?param=xx).

NOTE: The error doesn't occur just for one of the URLs with the forms, but randomly on both. Does the Not working response look familiar to anybody?

Comment: Thinking that the GET param from https://page.com?param=xx might affect the URL, I also changed :
"url: "/wp-content/api/api.php""  in   "var origin_url = window.location.origin;
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: origin_url+"/wp-content/api/api.php","

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was using a minification plugin that after a while was breaking the jQuery ajax call.
I solved it by implementing an inline script for the ajax call, using just javascript (no jQuery library dependency).